# Extension Method for System.environment

Tags: .net

Hi i want to add whitespace extension method in System.Enviroment but compiler give this error
**'System.Environment': static types cannot be used as parameters**
Kindly suggest some solution.

Comment: You can still create a new class, for exemple `EnvironmentEx`. If you want to have at least same methods than Environment class, you can wrap all available methods in your new class. It's exactly an extension method, but can help

Comment: Why would you want an extension method for this class?

Answer (score 3):

Since the Environment class is static, it's not possible to add extensions to that class.
I would suggest, if it's string manipulation, to add it to the string class instead

Comment: Why we cannot extend static class

Comment: The extension method requires an instance as first parameter. It's the way it is designed. From the C# 3.0 spec: "Extension methods are static methods that can be invoked using instance method syntax."